# I have low internal Storage, But i have no apps on my phone?

Tags: internal-storage

My phone is an Android Evo, and it keeps telling me I have low storage. I have removed everything - facebook, email, messages, text messages, and pictures, but it's still low.

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the `internal-storage` tag and click on the "info" link in that box. Update your question when you've tried the solutions provided there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Storage`.

This should list available space and the size of used space for apps, pictures, videos, music, downloads, etc.

You can use this as a guide to go through your storage and find files you can clean up.

Once you have figured out what is taking up a lot of space, then you can ask how to clear up a particular item.

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing out the cache files.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you explain how to go about doing this?

Comment: Caches are pretty small. So clearing it useless. Also apps will always rebuild cache once its cleared